# Execute batch script with admin rights in windows 8.1 by exec()

Tags: php, windows, batch-file, exec, admin

I am trying to run a batch file from php with exec() but it is not working. When I run the same script in a command window in admin mode the script works.

Now I want to know how can I configure in php that my script can be execute with ADMIN mode.

Comment: I believe that in most configurations, it is the web server rather than PHP that determines the security context in which a script runs.

Answer (score 6):

You can use [RunAs Command](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/runas.mspx?mfr=true). Since it will ask admin password and you are running it from web you should pipe the admin password to the command.

```
exec('echo adminpassword | runas /user:administrator fullPathToProgram',$output);
print_r($output);
```

Comment: Embedding an administrator password into a PHP script is a pretty good way to get hacked.

Comment: @HarryJohnston Yes of course... Also Using windows and enabling dangerous php functions like exec is another good way to get hacked...:)

Comment: @HarryJohnston Who says that the password isn't dynamically passed into the command from (administrator) user input and never stored? This is a completely fine approach.

Comment: @Steve, I don't think that's what the OP was asking to do, but I could be mistaken.  In retrospect, though, the main problem with this answer is that it won't work: `runas` filters the user token, so you don't get admin privilege even if you provide admin credentials.

Comment: @HarryJohnston Good point - reading it over I think you're right. By the way, do you know of an alternative to `runas`? I'm trying to have PHP automatically import a scheduled task XML file under the "SYSTEM" account, but it fails due to permissions - even when using the schtasks params (`/u`, `/p`)

Comment: @Steve, I think typically you would want to run the PHP script with elevated credentials, whether you can do that and how you would go about it depends on the scenario.