# httpd+php can't access network drive login using domain username

Tags: php, apache, network-drive

I run Apache+PHP (apache as a service) on Win7-64bit. My PHP issues commands:

```
system("net use z: \\srv\dir /user:dmn\uid \"\"");
system("copy z:\123.jpg d:\try");
system("net use z: /delete");
```

The manager of network server 'svr' gives me a domain user account 'dmn\svr' without password. I try above DOS commands manually in cmd.exe and it runs perfect. However, when I run PHP, it keeps returning messages: "Login failed: Unknown username or incorrect password".

I've tried to change the account to run Apache service to my local account but the result is in vain. I don't have privilege to touch the network server 'svr' so there's no way for me to change any configuration there (e.g. set nullsessservice in registry to 0). Is there a way to cut through this problem?

Comment: net use commands require administrator privileges, and having user with out password on domain controller needs to be considered very carefully

Comment: this might help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23410913/execute-batch-script-with-admin-rights-in-windows-8-1-by-exec